Startup screen during first time start
I have an iOS app where i create a SwiftData container in windowgroup from a JSON.
The first startup can take a while 4-5 seconds and only show a white screen. so i created a splash screen but it appears after the container is created.
I wonder if i could show this splash screen before the container is created?

Split it into two steps, 1. create the (empty) container 2. use .task to load the data
